# I'm trying to get the access token

Tags: php, rest, api, curl

```
$curl = curl_init();
$auth_data = array(
 'client_id'        => 'xxxxxxxx', // i have it
 'client_secret'    => 'xxxxxxxx', // I have it
 'grant_type'       => 'client_credentials'
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $auth_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://xxxxxx.caspio.com/oauth/token'); // I have it
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
curl_close($curl);
echo $result;
```

I would like to know why I'm getting `Bad Request`. When I try to show the errors it shows nothing.

Comment: there could be caused by `missing parameters` or `authentication` or missing `/` at the end of the URL or the URL you are using is currently not present `page not found`.

Comment: I put `/` at the end nof the URL and Now I'm getting this message `File or directory not found.`

Comment: A 400 Bad Request comes from the server; if it doesn't want to show you any errors, it won't. That's outside of your control. Check their documentation again or whatever you used to put the POST request together.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array( $curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "<TOKEN ENDPOINT URL>",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<client_ID>&client_secret=<Secret>",
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
```